# Minimal integration between Wordpress and Django

Tags: django, wordpress

I'm looking for a minimal example of integration between django and wordpress. I just want to collect the latest post from the category named "bar" on my wordpress and show it at django app.

I'm trying with https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/

Comment: What have you tried already? Are you able to retrieve a list of posts in JSON with the WordPress plugin? If you can do that, getting it in Django should not be hard (with the `requests` library for example).

Comment: Yes, sounds great, how can I start the tests using requests?

Comment: If they share the same db. Just write a raw query.

Comment: Not the same db. I'll probably have to use requests like Jan said. But a need a minimal code example of use requests library.

Comment: The requests quickstart guide contains a JSON example: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content